# Haskell mutable vectors have no map, fold, etc ... higher level functions?

Tags: haskell, vector, mutable

While using mutable vectors for the first time, I discovered that while `Data.Vector.Unboxed` has all the higher level functions you'd expected like `map`, `fold`, etc., the mutable version `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` has none of these. Trying to use the functions from the immutable package on mutable vectors didn't work.

What is the reason why the mutable vector package lacks a lot of these higher level functions?

Comment: Doesn't it get fused correctly if you write it as a composition of `fold` and `freeze`?

Comment: @Cactus I have no idea. There is no documentation on this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the designers of these types had in mind when implementing the mutable versions, but the problem I see is to do with laziness and the expectation of consistency.

Suppose I create a mutable vector of three ints, map `(* 2)` over them, and then modify the original vector. When I look at the output of map, will I see doubles of old values or of new values? The answer is, it depends on which elements I looked at before modifying, and which after. Consider:

```
main = do
  v <- V.replicate 3 1
  let doubled = map (* 2) v
  putStrLn "First doubled number is: " ++ show (head doubled)
  set v 10
  putStrLn "Sum of doubled numbers is: " ++ show (sum doubled)
```

Although we performed our operations in well-defined chunks, the caching of thunks means that the first element of `doubled` will be 2, because we had to force it in order to print it *before* we set the whole vector to 10, but the last two elements of `doubled` will be 20, so our sum is 42: neither the sum of double the original vector, nor the sum of double the final vector. We managed to observe an inconsistent state that our system as a whole was never intended to be in, because we treated a mutable vector as if it were an immutable list, by trying to `map` over it lazily.

Comment: How much would this apply for a _strict_ map?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not sure, because the values themselves can still be lazy. For example, suppose the function I mapped were instead `\x -> "Doubled number: " ++ (x * 2)`. Would this have the same problem even in a strict map? I'm not familiar enough with how haskell's thunking works to say.

Comment: Maybe if it were both spine-strict and value-strict, forcing each value to WHNF, it would work.

Comment: This is basically explaining why `map` and `fold` for mutable vectors would have to be `IO` (or `ST`) operations, since they need to read the current contents of the vector. Does the vector library not have those?

Comment: The vector library doesn't have those.